# jQuery: find words in a textarea paragraph and replacing it with word

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to translate a text/paragraph from its original English version to valley girl talk. So for instance, "hi" will be "hellloooooo, what is up?". The words have been entered into a database with the English word and its translated valley girl version. Example: English column-> hi, VG column-> hellloooooo, English-> yes, VG -> like, hells yes

I am using MySQL to get the translated words off the database and returning a json.

So this is how I'm retrieving it in AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "dictionary.php",
    success: function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        // replacing all the ing's with in'
        $("#textarea").each(function(){
            var ing = $(this).val().replace(/ing/g,"in'");
            $(this).val(ing);
            // finding the English words and replacing with VG 
            $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
                var vg= $("#content").val().replace(/obj.english/g, obj.vg);
                $("#textarea").val(vg);
            );
        });                 
    }
});
```

I got the "ing" replacements well and working but trying to replace the valley girl words is a no go. Am I looping through the json objects incorrectly?

EDIT: here is the json data

```
[{"english":"hi","0":"hi","vg":"hellloooooo!","1":"hellloooooo"},    {"english":"yes","0":"yes","vg":"like, hells yes","1":"like, hells yes"},.....]
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about "no go". What is the result, exactly?

Comment: @CindyMeister meaning the words aren't being replaced

Comment: Doesn't make sense changing the textarea value once...then replacing that value every iteration of a loop from different source. Also ID's must be unique so `$("#textarea").each` is a smell for problems

Comment: can you show an example of the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see this small example of replacing the words, then outputting this to a new field, this may help with what you want to achieve.

it loops over each word and goes for an exact word match, you may run into issues if some of the translations also contain words in english

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 var json = [{"english":"hi","0":"hi","vg":"hellloooooo!","1":"hellloooooo"},    {"english":"yes","0":"yes","vg":"like, hells yes","1":"like, hells yes"}];

var userInput = $('#textarea').val();

json.forEach(function(word){
  console.log(word);
  userInput = userInput.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+word.english+"\\b","g"),word.vg);
});
  $('#translation').val(userInput);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="textarea">
    hi this is a test of yes translation. hi yes
  </textarea>
  <textarea id="translation">
  
  </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have several logical mistakes. You're looping over a jQuery selection where an id is used? An id is always treated as unique regardless of what you do, hence it's called id :) Then you're replacing the value of the html element every time (which just happens to be once in this case but that's a mistake on your part I assume).

Answer (score 0):

I changed your html a bit so that your code will work correctly.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea class="text">
            hi this is a text area what  is going on? hi how are you? yes, I am fine.
</textarea>

<textarea class="text">
            hi this is a text area what is going on? hi how are you? yes, I am fine.
</textarea>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "dictionary.php",
            type:"GET",
            success: function(data) {

            //store the parsed json
            var json = JSON.parse(data);                 


         //loop through the .text elements
        $(".text").each(function(){//begin outer each

            //reference the current object
            var that = $(this);

            //replace the all of the ing's with in'
            var ing = $(this).val().replace(/ing/g,"in'");

            $(this).val(ing);

            // finding the English words and replacing with VG 
            $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {//begin inner each

                //Create a new regular expression that matches the word only.
                var regExp = new RegExp("\\b" + obj.english,"g");

                //Replace the value of the text value with the vg value and store it.
                var vg = that.val().replace(regExp, obj.vg);

                //Replace the value of the .text text area in the dom.
                that.val(vg);


            });//<-- was missing a closing } bracket. //end inner each

        });//end outer each    


            }
});
```